# Why is the question tagged twice with the same tag and yet the question count does not match ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, specific-question

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/189172/cant-install-chromium-x64-error-o) has been tagged twice with [windows-7-x64]. Oddly, the same tag shows up twice, with different counts. Clicking on each of those tags, brings the same questions, although one less than the actual count. What's happening ?

---

[image: tags]

---

[image: tags-on-question]

---

[image: search-for-tags]

Comment: Nice catch. Something's not quite right there!

Comment: Uh oh! There is [another](http://superuser.com/questions/189287/sync-setup-question-android-outlook-2010-gmail-calendar) one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means a moderator renamed a tag. renames don't protect against dupes.

In the future just flag this and I can run the global tag deduplication routine.

Comment: meaning there was another tag, eg: `win-7-x64` and it was renamed to the proper tag ?

Comment: Some other mod did that retag, but an earlier mass retag back in August moved from [windows-7-x64] to [64-bit] with [windows-7] @sat

Comment: ah gotcha @Random