# Bugs with tagging questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

While editing a post tonight I noticed this bug with the tags. There were two of the same tag (windows-7-x64), and several tags with 0 uses but still showing up. Seems broken, unless I'm missing something.

[double tags http://c0848462.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/0d97cf189dd1ccc237d8b790fc3b3c3a.png](http://c0848462.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/0d97cf189dd1ccc237d8b790fc3b3c3a.png)

Comment: This may be tied in with http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1450/why-is-the-question-tagged-twice-with-the-same-tag-and-yet-the-question-count-doe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is temporary -- tags are cleaned up every 24 hours so it is possible for bad (not used, recently destroyed) tags to be in the system for a bit.

Notice that none of those [windows7-hide*] tags are present now.

The (s) tag you are seeing is a synonym, so people who insist on using the "wrong" form of a tag can find it; that tag will be auto-remapped to the synonym.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Jeff.